# Babel-node: one await works, more than one doesn't; breaks with SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, firebase, babeljs

I have a script that I run with `babel-node` and it works with one `await` in it, but when I add another `await`, it throws a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token` error that looks something like this:

```
SyntaxError: C:/Users/User/Documents/thing/updateFirebase.js: Unexpected token (73:12)
    [0m  71 |                                      [31m'votes'[39m[1m:[22m [35m0[39m
  72 |                          [32m}[39m[1m;[22m
> 73 |                          await writeNewData[94m[1m([22m[39mcard[1m.[22mname[1m,[22m newData[1m,[22m newEditionArrayId[94m[1m)[22m[39m[1m;[22m
     |             ^
  74 |                  [32m}[39m
  75 |                  [32m}[39m
  76 |                  [36melse[39m [32m{[39m [90m
```

I'm using Firebase's realtime database and my first await is simply waiting to get a chunk of data:

```
let snapshot = await dbRef.once('value');
```

Then I do a bunch of other stuff, go into a loop and do this:

```
await writeNewData(book.name, newData, newEditionArrayId);
```

And this is the called function:

```
function writeNewData(name, object, arrayId) {
    var localMidRef = Firebase.database().ref(name + "/editions/"+ arrayId);
    console.log("writing new data to "+name);
    return localMidRef.set(object);
}
```

I assume `set()` works asynchronously, since you can pass it a callback (I haven't found any documentation in Firebase's docs on it to prove otherwise...). But I can't understand why the damn await keyword screws up the parsing on the second usage, and not the first.

My `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
  "plugins": ["syntax-async-functions","transform-regenerator"]
}
```

If I put `stage-0` in there it all stops working.

Comment: I dont think its the await. What is the full error msg, whats the unexpected token?

Comment: Added the error msg to OP. I don't know which token it is, since the error message also has these rectangle chars and that's the one the arrow is pointing at.

Comment: When you say "go into a loop" are you using `forEach`? Because they your `await` would be inside the foreach callback, which isn't an async function. Show us the real code that calls `writeNewData`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Ah, yes... yes it is. That's probably why. I assume switching it out for a normal `for` loop would fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

First fix your prompt to show ANSI colors instead of the escape codes, so we don't have to guess where the error was.  https://serverfault.com/questions/106028/how-to-enable-ansi-escape-codes-in-windows-cmd

You can also do a simple isolated test with await and babel to make sure that isn't the problem.

Comment: I know it isn't, because my first await works fine. It does `let snapshot = await dbRef.once('value')` just fine. Oh and thanks for the escape colours thing... I had no idea what was causing all those boxes...